# Apply multiple styles with SASS

Tags: sass

I have 2 styles that I need to apply to elements with SASS:

```
.one {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}
.two {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}
.three {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

How can I do this in a DRY method? I cant see how from the documentarian.

Variables seem to only pass one rule. Mixins pass multiple but I dont need a variable.
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not simply a case of doing:-

```
.one,
.two,
.three {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

Or, better:-

```
.thing {
 max-width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}
```

and apply the class 'thing' where needed. This doesn't really appear to need a Sass specific solution. Unless you wanted to extend the latter example as:-

```
.one { @extend .thing; }
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @drmonkeyninja, except I would use a placeholder (%) instead of a class, especially if the class isn't going to be used on the site. Otherwise, the resulting CSS will contain a redundant class:

```
.thing,
.one,
.two,
.three {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

So instead, you could do this:

```
%thing {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  @extend %thing;
}
```

Which would result in the following CSS, which only contains the classes your site will use:

```
.one,
.two,
.three {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
}
```